# Keep value of UICollectionView Cell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

There is a label in UICollectionViewCell.
I made 6 cells in UICollectionView and assigned a number (1-6) to a label in each cell.
I call [UICollectionView reloadData] and expect same number in label.
But, a label value is changed when cellForItemAtIndexPathas is called, like "1 3 1 3 1 3".
It seems UICollectionViewCell is relocated in cellForItemAtIndexPathas.

Is there any way to keep it?

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    InfoCollectionViewCell *infoCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"InfoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [infoCell.cellText setText:[infoCell.cellText.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d\n",indexPath.row]]];

    return infoCell;
}
```

Comment: The cells are usually 'made' within `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, typically by calling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`, but I get the sense from the question that's not what you're doing.  Without looking at the code, it is very difficult to get a sense for what might be going wrong there.  I would suggest adding some sample code to your question - would make it a lot easier to answer.

Comment: My code is attached. I expect infoCell.cellText label is same whenever this is called. However, This is changed in random.

Answer (score 0):

You have a reuse issue with the label that you added to your cell.

I made a post about how to subclass UICollectionViewCell properly.
You can check it here :
[UICollectionView adding image to a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801418/uicollectionview-adding-image-to-a-cell/23802296#23802296)

Comment: Thanks. I found "dequeue". So, it will reuse after dequeue.