# Save UICollectionViewCell progress state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiprogressview

I've already asked the same question about saving pressed button state and I thought that I should do in the same way to save progress state on cells but my tries are unsuccessful.

What I'm doing now: I select some `UICollectionViewCell's` and then press "download" button and then downolad action starts. Every cell I selected shows `UIProgressView` and everything is ok untill I scroll my `UICollectionView` up or down. When I do it another cells have progress view too but they mustn't! I know that I must save `indexPath` of selected cells in `NSMutableArray` and then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` check if current cell indexPath is in my array and then show or hide my cell's subviews. I do that but it only works with cell selection! What should I do to save progress view state on each cell this progress really there?

Here is my code:

**In `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:**

```
 NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)indexPath.row];
if ([selecedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]  )
{

    cell.selectedBG.hidden = NO;
    cell.selectedImg.hidden = NO;


}
else
{

    cell.selectedBG.hidden = YES;
    cell.selectedImg.hidden = YES;
    cell.progressView.hidden = YES;


}
```

**In `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
        // Add the selected item into the array
        [selectedIds addObject:selectedId];
        [selectedVideos addObject:selectedVideo];
        AVMVideoCell *collectionCell = (AVMVideoCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)indexPath.row];
        if ( ![selecedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]  )
        {
            [selecedCellsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
            collectionCell.selectedBG.hidden = NO;
            collectionCell.selectedImg.hidden = NO;
            [collectionCell setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

**In `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`:**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ...

    // Delete the selected item from the array
    [selectedIds removeObject:selectedId];
    [selectedVideos removeObject:selectedVideo];
    AVMVideoCell *collectionCell = (AVMVideoCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)indexPath.row];
    if ( [selecedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]  )
    {
        [selecedCellsArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
        collectionCell.selectedBG.hidden = YES;
        collectionCell.selectedImg.hidden = YES;
        [collectionCell setSelected:NO];

    }
}
```

And this is how I show my progress:

```
-(NSString *)progress:(long long )val1 : (long long )val2 : (AVMVideoCell *)cell : (NSString *)name : (NSIndexPath *)path{

float progress = ((float)val1) / val2;
NSString *prog = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress*100] stringValue];
if (prog != nil){
    if(cell.isSelected){
    cell.selectedImg.hidden = YES;
    cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
    }
}


NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)path.row];
if ( [selecedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]])
{
[cell.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
}

if([prog intValue]==100){
    cell.progressView.hidden = YES;

}
return prog;
}
```

**EDIT: AVMVideoCell.m**

```
#import "AVMVideoCell.h"


@implementation AVMVideoCell
{
    NSString *fullUrl;
}
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize selectedBG;
@synthesize progressLabel;
@synthesize progressView;
@synthesize selectedImg;
@synthesize progLayer;

-(void) setVideo:(AVMDataStore *)video {
if(_video != video) {
    _video = video;
}
NSString *durString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self timeFormatted:_video.duration]];
if((_video.filePreview != nil) && ![_video.filePreview isEqualToString:@""]){
fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com%@",_video.filePreview];
}

NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullUrl];

[self.imageView setImageWithURL:imgURL
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yesterday.png"] options:0 usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
self.duration.text = durString;

}

- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds
{

int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds];
}
@end
```

**EDIT 2: Explanation about progress**
 My progressView is not an `IBOutlet` it's a `@property (nonatomic,strong) UIProgressView *progressView;` (AVMVideoCell.h)

I allocate and initialize it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 150.0f, 1.0f)];
cell.progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:0.5f];
cell.progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell.progLayer addSubview:cell.progressView];
cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
cell.progressView.tag = indexPath.row+500;
```

This is where I call progress change showing:

```
-(void)downloadStart:(NSString*)fileUrl : (NSString*)name : (AVMVideoCell *) cell : (NSIndexPath *)path{

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",name]; //set full file name to save
AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloadRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request]; //create download request
[downloadRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:responseObject];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pathToFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths firstObject],fileName]; // path to 'Documents'

    NSString *pathOfFile = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:pathOfFile append:NO];
   BOOL success =  [data writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES];
    if(success){
         [self checkIfExists:name : cell :path];
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"file downloading error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
    [alert show];
    cell.progressView.hidden = YES;

}];
// Step 5: begin asynchronous download
[downloadRequest start];
[downloadRequest setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

    [self progress:totalBytesRead :totalBytesExpectedToRead :cell :name : path]; //here I pass val1 and val 2


  }];

}
```

When I select an items in collection view, I gather their model's objects, get each id and make array of urls, then in for..in loop i pass urls one by one and then start async download. You can see how I download and call progress method above.

Comment: can you paste your entire AVMVideoCell.m code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to know if you have a reuse issue or a model issue.

So first try this :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...

    if (![selectedIds.containsObject:selectedId])
    {
        // Add the selected item into the array
        [selectedIds addObject:selectedId];
        [selectedVideos addObject:selectedVideo];
        AVMVideoCell *collectionCell = (AVMVideoCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)indexPath.row];
        if ( ![selecedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]  )
        {
            [selecedCellsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
            collectionCell.selectedBG.hidden = NO;
            collectionCell.selectedImg.hidden = NO;
            [collectionCell setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
    else {
    // Delete the selected item from the array
    [selectedIds removeObject:selectedId];
    [selectedVideos removeObject:selectedVideo];
    AVMVideoCell *collectionCell = (AVMVideoCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)indexPath.row];
    if ( [selecedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]  )
    {
        [selecedCellsArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
        collectionCell.selectedBG.hidden = YES;
        collectionCell.selectedImg.hidden = YES;
        [collectionCell setSelected:NO];
    }
}
```

and remove the didDeselect delegate.

Let me know what happens then.

EDIT :

Ok try this now:

```
// Lazy instantiation of the progressView
- (UIProgressView *)progressView
{
    if (!_progressView)
    {
        _progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 150.0f, 1.0f)];
        _progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:0.5f];
        _progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _progressView.hidden = YES;

        [self.contentView addSubview:_progressView];
    }

    return _progressView;
}


// Here we remove the progressView on reuse
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.progressView removeFromSuperview];
    self.progressView = nil;
}
```

Also remove what you did with the progressView with in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method.

Comment: nothing has changed. besides now I must press 2 times to select/deselect my cell. I'm sure that I've reuse issue

Comment: Is your progressview an iboutlet ? Where do you call progress:val1:val2 ?

Comment: I made a post a while ago about this kind of issues : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801418/uicollectionview-adding-image-to-a-cell/23802296#23802296 . Check it if you want more informations

Comment: wow! amazing! thank you very much! works like a charm!) should I do the same way if my progressview is an `IBOutlet`?

Comment: No you don't need to do it for iboutlets

Answer (score 1):

You can create class for cell's models, store these models in array in your viewController and use them to get/set all states from/for cells.
Something like this:

```
@interface CellModel : NSObject
    @property(nonatomic) BOOL selected;
    @property(nonatomic) NSUInteger progress;
@end
```

In viewController:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic) NSArray* models;
@end
```

Comment: then I need to implement this model into my custom cell class?

Comment: @vendettacore yes, you can pass that model to each cell when you dequeue them. Then if you need to update progress you can grab all visible cells and update progress for ones that are visible on screen.

Comment: I think more better is using separate file for implementation of CellModel