# Create UICollectionReusableView programmatically overlapping issue

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

So seems `-addSubview` twice add `UILabel` to the `UICollectionReusableView`

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {

        UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (reusableview==nil) {
            reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        }

        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recipe Group #%i", indexPath.section + 1];
        [reusableview addSubview:label];
        return reusableview;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This code does not work:

```
if (reusableview==nil) {
   reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
}
```

So the reusable view is never nill.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize a UICollectionReusableView, you need to subclass it the same way you would for a UICollectionViewCell. Else you're basically adding a label everytime your reusableview is reused (on scroll or reloadData for ex).

I made a post about that a while ago : [UICollectionView adding image to a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801418/uicollectionview-adding-image-to-a-cell)

Just do the same thing for your reusableview and let me know if it solves your problem.