# Get info from selected collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to print the `cell.image.text` from collection view cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath.row]
        cell.currentUserLabel.text = post.username
        cell.imageText.text = post.text

        cell.uploadedTimeLabel.text = post.CreatedAt.timeAgo

        cell.imageView.setImageWithUrl(NSURL(string: post.image)!, placeHolderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))

        return cell
    }
```

ArrayOfDetails:

```
var arrayOfDetails = [Details]()
```

Details:

```
struct Details {
    var username:String!
    var text:String!
    var CreatedAt:NSDate!
    var image:String!
    init(username:String,text:String,CreatedAt:NSDate,image:String){

        self.username = username
        self.text = text
        self.CreatedAt = CreatedAt
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

This is like a Instagram app, so there are multiple cells with photos and photo text, and i have a button, and when the button is pressed, it want to `println(cell.image.text)`. How can i do this?

I tried:

```
@IBAction func printButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: nil) as! CollectionViewCell

        println(cell.imageText.text)
    }
```

But it did not show any text.

Comment: You have a print button inside each cell ?

Comment: Yes, a flag button. And i want in the `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` to detect when the flag button is pressed. How to do this?

Comment: Why especially in the didDeselectItemAtIndexPath ? You could just subclass your cell, give it a uibutton property and set its behavior inside your collectionviewcustomcell.m.

Comment: Like how? (In swift)

Comment: :D I've made a reponse a while ago, but it's in objective C : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801418/uicollectionview-adding-image-to-a-cell/23802296#23802296 . Can you understand it or should I explain ?

Comment: @Kujey - Please explain, i have never used Obj-C :D

Comment: I'll make an answer for that, however i've kind of stopped working on Xcode for a while so there will be very few lines of codes

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get the *cell* what if you just got the data itself? Don't look at the `collectionView`(emphasis on **View**), instead pull up data from the **Data** Source.

You could use

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and in that method call

```
println(self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath.row].text)
```

if you wanted to print out the text when the user selects the cell.

Comment: I want to print out the text when the user press a specific button inside the cell. Each cell has a report button, and when they press, i want to do the println code.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my syntax errors, I've never done swift :D

First of all you create a CustomCollectionViewCell, which subclasses CollectionViewCell.

Now in the header, give it a printButton property :

```
var printButton: UIButton!
```

Then in the CustomCollectionViewCell class implementation :

```
// This is lazy loading, everytime something needs to talk to the printButton 
// of a cell, it checks if this button exists. If not, it will be created.
lazy var printButton: UIButton = 
{
    var temporaryButton: UIButton = UIButton()
    temporaryButton.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    temporaryButton.addTarget(self action: @selector(printText), forControlEvents: TouchUpInside);
    self.contentView.addSubview(temporaryButton);
    return temporaryButton;
}()

    return _printButton;
}
```

Then you remove your printButton when your subclassed cell is reused:

```
func prepareForReuse()
{
    super.prepareForReuse();

    self.printButton.removeFromSuperview().
    self.printButton = nil;
}
```

Finally you implement your printText function

```
func printText()
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: nil) as! CollectionViewCell

    println(cell.imageText.text)
}
```

Comment: Sorry i didn´t understand this. Where to do put the first line of code?

Comment: It's just the declaration of a new property for your CustomCollectionViewCell