# collectionViewCell Images change when scrolling up down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a `tableviewcell` having `collectionview` which has a custom `collectionviewcell`.
I created a controller, having Custom `tableviewcell`. TableViewCell has `collectionview` embeded. Now i created a custom `collectioncell` with **image** and **text**.

In `collectionViewcell` the 4th image needs to be translucent so when i am rendering the images in **cellforitematindex** i make the image translucent. it is completely working fine till i scroll the tableview down and up. After we scroll up the first image turns translucent.

I read on net that `collectionviewcell` are up for reuse and may be the 4th one reused at 1st position and 1st position gets translucent image

I have a controller class which is the datasource and delegate for both **tableviewcell** and **collectionviewcell**.

```
I have tableviewcell class.
I have collectionviewcell class.
```

Now i get a link to solve this , which says you must subclass your `collectionviewcell` and add some methods which would make `imageview` nil everytime and it will create a new `imageview` .

[Link for the above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801418/uicollectionview-adding-image-to-a-cell/23802296#23802296)

so i created a collectionviewcell subclass

```
I have a subclass of collectionviewcell : uicollectionviewsubclass
```

In my controller , first i reuse tablecell

So I Created a controller Lets say:-

mycontroller and added a tableview , i added a custom tableviewcell ,
At `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier , so my tableviewcell will come. Now In my tableViewcell .m file I created an outlet for collectionview and by using tag I make

```
self.collectionview = [self.contentView viewWithTag:tagno];
```

> This tag is a collectionviewcell tagno

Now i register the `collectionview` in `tableviewcell` class , it has outlet for `collectionview`

`[self.collectionview registerClass:[uicollectionviewsubclass class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseidentifier"];`

In my `collectionviewcell` , i have `imageview` outlet and other outlets

when i created subclass i created like said in link.

Then in my controller in **cellForItemAtIndexPath** for **collectionview**

```
uicollectionviewsubclass *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseidentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but this cell is a subclassed cell which is not having outlet for imageview (whihc is in collectionview class) 
so it is showing imageView in self as nil not instantiated.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     ImageCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.ImageCellView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            cell.grayViewImage.hidden = FALSE;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

> `grayViewImage` is a uiview which i make hidden false to make the cell
>   translucent

What may be the reason.

Comment: can you show us code of collection view cellforitematindex?

Comment: I put it there as you asked @Alok

Comment: one more thing how you have added ImageCellView ? its added to cell.contentView or added direct to [cell addSubview:ImageCellView]; ?

Comment: Its added to cell.contentview by tagging the collection view

Comment: what ? by tagging the collection view ? and it is nil if you debug in above posted cellForItem.. ? very confusing line "but this cell is a subclassed cell which is not having outlet for imageview"? so have outlet what's prob ?

Comment: Please use `code formatting` for `code`, not for **emphasis**.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue you should prepare your cell to be reused. Use a  method called `prepareForReuse` for `UICollectionViewCell` and `UITableViewCell`.
Implement it like this and call it in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)prepareForReuse 
{
    yourImageView .image = nil;
    [super prepareForReuse];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the gap in your code:

Easy: You missed that else part see below :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

             ImageCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.ImageCellView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
            if (indexPath.row == 3) {
                    cell.grayViewImage.hidden = FALSE;
            }else{
    cell.grayViewImage.hidden = TRUE;
    }
            return cell;
        }
```

Thanks !